# Python-Top Ten Function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a function where the user puts in the year and the output is the top ten countries by expenditures using this [Lynda class](https://www.lynda.com/Numpy-tutorials/yearly-top-ten/419162/446742-4.html) as a model.

Here's the data frame

```
df.dtypes
Country Name     object
Country Code     object
Year              int32
CountryYear      object
Population        int32
GDP             float64
MilExpend       float64
Percent         float64
dtype: object



   Country Name Country Code    Year    CountryYear Pop         GDP   Expend    Percent
0   Aruba       ABW             1960    ABW-1960    54208       0.0   0.0       0.0
```

I've tried this code and got errors:

Code:

```
def topten(Year):
    simple = df_details_merged.loc[Year].sort('MilExpend',ascending=False).reset_index()
    simple = simple.drop(['Country Code', 'CountryYear'],axis=1).head(10)
    simple.index = simple.index + 1

    return simple
    topten(1990)
```

This is the rather big error I received: 
Can I get some assistance? I can't even figure out what the error is. :-(

```
C:\Users\mycomputer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:2: FutureWarning: sort is deprecated, use sort_values(inplace=True) for INPLACE sorting
  from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\mycomputer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _try_kind_sort(arr)
   1738                 # if kind==mergesort, it can fail for object dtype
-> 1739                 return arr.argsort(kind=kind)
   1740             except TypeError:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-0c974c6a1b44> in <module>()
----> 1 topten(1990)

<ipython-input-104-b8c336014d5b> in topten(Year)
      1 def topten(Year):
----> 2     simple = df_details_merged.loc[Year].sort('MilExpend',ascending=False).reset_index()
      3     simple = simple.drop(['Country Code', 'CountryYear'],axis=1).head(10)
      4     simple.index = simple.index + 1
      5 

C:\Users\mycomputer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in sort(self, axis, ascending, kind, na_position, inplace)
   1831 
   1832         return self.sort_values(ascending=ascending, kind=kind,
-> 1833                                 na_position=na_position, inplace=inplace)
   1834 
   1835     def order(self, na_last=None, ascending=True, kind='quicksort',

C:\Users\mycomputer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in sort_values(self, axis, ascending, inplace, kind, na_position)
   1751         idx = _default_index(len(self))
   1752 
-> 1753         argsorted = _try_kind_sort(arr[good])
   1754 
   1755         if not ascending:

C:\Users\mycomputer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _try_kind_sort(arr)
   1741                 # stable sort not available for object dtype
   1742                 # uses the argsort default quicksort
-> 1743                 return arr.argsort(kind='quicksort')
   1744 
   1745         arr = self._values

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `sort_values` instead? `sort` is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you @Denziloe I changed that and got another error. I can't include the whole error bc of character limits but the last line was   ValueError: No axis named MilExpend for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: Check what `df_details_merged.loc[Year]` is. Apparently it's a Series, which doesn't take a column argument to sort_values (because there's only one column).

Comment: @Denziloe Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you check what that thing is? Run the `type` function on it. Presumably it will tell you it's a `pandas.Series`. So this means `.sort_values` is a method of a Series object, not a DataFrame object. So you need to read for yourself how to call that method. You can either Google the documentation, or run `help(Series.sort_values)`.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `.loc` is the *row* label.

When you call `df_details_merged.loc[1960]`, pandas will find the row with the label `1960` and return that row as a Series. So you get back a Series with the index `Country Name, Country Code, ...`, with the values being the values from that row. Then your code tries to sort this by `MilExpend`, and that's where it fails.

What you need isn't `loc`, but a simple condition: `df[df.Year == Year]`. That is "give me the whole dataframe, but only where the 'Year' column contains whatever I've specified in the "Year" variable (1960 in your example).

`sort` will still work for the time being, but is being deprecated, so use `sort_values` instead. Putting that together:

`simple = df_details_merged[df_details_merged.Year == Year].sort_values(by='MilExpend', ascending=False).reset_index()`

Then you can go ahead and drop the columns, and fetch the top 10 rows as you're doing now.

Comment: Thank you @stephan! The great news was that there was no error. when i put in topten(1980) and the columns were presented but no data afterward. Do you have any idea what happened? Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's difficult to say without seeing the data, but it sounds like (for whatever reason) nothing in your DataFrame is matching the condition (year==1980). So it would be worth checking your data carefully before you run the function. Try just running `df[df.Year == 1980]` in the interactive shell and seeing whether any rows are returned. 1)

Comment: sorry  @Stephan.... Family issues came up. I still only got a column when I put in your suggestion. Can I email you offline perhaps?